# How to get the data value from all items in one string

Tags: jquery

I have a variating amount of items which are grouped in different lists. The user can change the items by drag and drop. After each change I need to display a string with all items and how they are grouped. The string contains the data-value from the item, not the text.

Getting the items data-values was no problem, but I don´t know how to go on to build the string.

```
<input type="text" id="listOfItems">

<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="A">Item A</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="B">Item B</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="C">Item C</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="D">Item D</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="E">Item E</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="F">Item F</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="G">Item G</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="H">Item H</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="I">Item I</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(".group").each(
        function (index) {
            $("li", this).data("value")
            //Next steps?
        }
    );
</script>
```

The required result is the string "(A,B,C),(D,E,F),(G,H,I)" within the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.map` twice, once over each `.group` (to put parentheses around its values), and in a nested one, over each `.item`, to get the value from each:

```js
const str = $('.group')
  .map(function() {
    return (
      '(' +
      $(this).find('.item').map(function() {
        return $(this).data('value');
      })
      .get()
      .join(',') +
      ')'
    )
  })
  .get()
  .join(',');
  
$('#listOfItems').val(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="listOfItems">

<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="A">Item A</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="B">Item B</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="C">Item C</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="D">Item D</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="E">Item E</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="F">Item F</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="G">Item G</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="H">Item H</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="I">Item I</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery makes this a bit ugly IMO, I'd prefer a solution without it:

```js
const str = [...document.querySelectorAll('.group')]
  .map(group => (
    '(' +
    [...group.querySelectorAll('.item')].map(item => item.dataset.value) +
    ')'
  ))
  .join(',');
document.querySelector('#listOfItems').value = str;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="listOfItems">

<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="A">Item A</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="B">Item B</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="C">Item C</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="D">Item D</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="E">Item E</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="F">Item F</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="G">Item G</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="H">Item H</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="I">Item I</li>
</ul>
```

Or, if the uls can be empty, check if the array has a length first:

```js
const str = $('.group')
  .map(function() {
    const valueArr = $(this)
      .find('.item').map(function() {
        return $(this).data('value');
      })
      .get();
    if (valueArr.length) {
      return '(' + valueArr.join(',') + ')';
    }
  })
  .get()
  .filter(Boolean)
  .join(',');
  
$('#listOfItems').val(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="listOfItems">

<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="A">Item A</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="B">Item B</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="C">Item C</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="D">Item D</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="E">Item E</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="F">Item F</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="G">Item G</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="H">Item H</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="I">Item I</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
</ul>
```

```js
const str = [...document.querySelectorAll('.group')]
  .map(group => {
    const arr = [...group.querySelectorAll('.item')].map(item => item.dataset.value);
    if (arr.length) {
      return '(' + arr + ')';
    }
  })
  .filter(Boolean)
  .join(',');
document.querySelector('#listOfItems').value = str;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="listOfItems">

<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="A">Item A</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="B">Item B</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="C">Item C</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="D">Item D</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="E">Item E</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="F">Item F</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="G">Item G</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="H">Item H</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="I">Item I</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will ignore any empty ULs

jQuery

```js
let arr = [];
$("[data-value]:first-child").each((_,ele) =>  {
  let text = [];
  $(ele).parent().children().each((_,ele) => text.push($(ele).attr("data-value")))
  arr.push("("+text.join(",")+")")
})

$("#listOfItems").val(arr.join(","));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="listOfItems">

<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="A">Item A</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="B">Item B</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="C">Item C</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="G">Item G</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="H">Item H</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="I">Item I</li>
</ul>
```

Plain JS

```js
let arr = [];
document.querySelectorAll("[data-value]:first-child").forEach(f => {
  let text = [];
  for (let sibling of f.parentNode.children) text.push(sibling.getAttribute("data-value"))
  arr.push("("+text.join(",")+")")
})

document.getElementById("listOfItems").value = arr.join(",");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="listOfItems">

<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="A">Item A</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="B">Item B</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="C">Item C</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="G">Item G</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="H">Item H</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="I">Item I</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through each group and, inside that, iterate through all `li` elements. Get an array of item in each iteration and generate a comma separated string through `Array.join`

```js
var allValues = $(".group").get().map(function (aGroup) {
        
                       
      var values = $(aGroup).children('li').get().map(function(item) {
          return $(item).data('value');
      })

      return `(${values.join(',')})`;
      
 })
     
  
  $('#listOfItems').val(allValues.join(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="listOfItems">

<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="A">Item A</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="B">Item B</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="C">Item C</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="D">Item D</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="E">Item E</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="F">Item F</li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li class="item" data-value="G">Item G</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="H">Item H</li>
    <li class="item" data-value="I">Item I</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that this will add a ,(), if a group is empty